# Spark 2.4 & Java 11 compatibility

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

Reading from given path with pyspark (Spark 2.4/Java 11)

```
df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(path_to_read)
```

fails, due to

> IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'

I run Spark on Java 11 (jdk-11.0.2), and checking on [Spark 2.4 overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/), I'm wondering if Spark 2.4 support Java 11?

Thanks

Comment: See [scala compatibility chart](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html).

Comment: Spark 2.4 does not support Java 11 (linked to Scala). Maybe Spark 3.

Comment: Work in progress but not release now ,so ans No

Comment: is there some progress in this?